computing local cohomlogy of a polynomial ideal
I am relatively new in computing cohomology. So I am not sure if my question is trivial. I will ask anyway. So I read somewhere that given the polynomial ring $R=k[w,x,y,z]$, where k is any field (preferably characteristic 0), the second local cohomology $H^2_I(R)$ of the ideal $I=\langle x,y \rangle$ is generated as a $k[w,z]$-module by
$$\{x^iy^j : i<0, j<0 \}$$
I don't quite understand why this is so. The author says that this is because it is the Macaulay inverse system of $x,y$. I don't know what Macaulay inverse systems are. If this is easy to explain without Macaulay inverse systems, then I'd appreciate some help. If it is easy to explain Macaulay inverse systems in a few words, I would also appreciate that.
As a followup: Can we use the Macaulay inverse system technique in general? Say for an arbitrary ideal of $R$? If not, for what ideals $I$ would it be easy to compute $H^2_I(R)$? Perhaps if my ideals are monomial ideals or ideals generated by linear forms? I just want to have enough material to get a good feel for computing these local cohomologies. As abstract objects, they are fine but I also want to have have practical examples to work with. I know how to compute the Koszul complexes but once I start thinking about the cohomologies I lose insight. Is it easier to think of these local cohomology using Cech complexes (they are more intimidating to me because they are generally not finitely generated).
I understand that most people don't compute these objects specifically, but how else would one know if they are: trivial, finitely generated, free, etc.? Are there any useful techniques? Would a geometric understanding of the zero-set of these ideals help?

Let me address the first question(s). This depends on how you define the local cohomology modules. A very popular reference is the book Local Cohomology by Brodmann and Sharp. If you use their definition, then you will see that the $i$-th local cohomology with respect to $I$ is isomorphic to the $i$-th cohomology of the Čech complex with respect to generators of $I$ (somewhere in Chapter 5 of the book e.g. Theorem 5.1.20). The book then gives explicit examples and how to compute the cohomologies. Notably example 5.1.6 where they compute the Čech cohomology with respect to 3 generators. And this gives you an idea how to compute the particular example you have in mind.
In your case, $H^2_I(R)$ is a special case of Example 13.5.3 of the book. You get the negative powers of $x$ and $y$ because of these "localizations" you have when creating the Čech complex. You don't have the positive powers of $x$ and $y$ because it is mod out when you compute the cohomology from the complex (you mod out with the image of the differential map). This is explicitly explained in the book. I hope this helps!
